# Юный, уне — этимология

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести слова "юный" и "уне" к этимологически однокоренным?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, это разные слова.

Значение слова "УНЕ" в толковом словаре Даля

> УНЕ - и унее или унше нареч. церк. лучше. *уне есть единому ЧЕЛОВЕКу
>   умрети за люди, иоан. унее ему было бы, аще жернов оселский облежал бы
>   о выи его.* лук. унший, лучший.

http://dal.sci-lib.com/word040985.html

Успенский:

> Форма «юноша» — старославянская; чисто русским было «у́ноша», «у́ный»,
>   как «уг» при старославянском «юг».

Фасмер:

> ю́ный ю́н, ю́на, ю́но, юне́ц, ю́ница, ю́ноша. Заимств. из цслав., судя
>   по наличию ю- при исконном у-; см. Шахматов, Очерк 142; укр. ю́ний,
>   стар., др.-русск. унъ «молодой, юный», уность, уноша, уница, ст.-слав.
>   юнъ νέος, νεώτερος (Остром., Супр.), стар. болг. юн (Младенов 700),
>   юне́ц, юне́ ср. р. «бычок», юна́к «герой», сербохорв. jу́нац, род. п.
>   jýнца «бычок», jу̀ница «телка», словен. junóta, собир., ж. «молодежь»,
>   júnǝс «бычок, жук-олень», др.-чеш. junec «бычок», junoch «юноша», чеш.
>   jinoch «юноша», слвц. junač ж. «молодежь», junák «парень, смельчак»,
>   польск. junosza, junoch «юноша», juniec «бычок», junak «юноша»,
>   н.-луж. диал. junk «бычок», полаб. jä́unac «бычок, тягловый скот»
>   Праслав. *junъ, *junьcь родственно лит. jáunas «молодой», лтш. jaûns
>   — то же, лит. jaunìkis «жених, молодожен», др.-инд. yúvan-, род. п.
>   уū́nаs «молодой, юноша», сравн. степ. yávīyān, превосх. yáviṣṭhas,
>   авест. yuvan-, род. п. уūnō, лат. iuvenis, iūnior, iuvencus «бычок»,
>   гот. juggs. Балто-слав. вокализм и интонация соответствуют сравн.
>   степ., а формант -nо-, вероятно, из антонима *sеnоs «старый» (Мейе,
>   МSL 14, 360); см. Траутман, ВSW 106 и сл.; Остхоф, МU 6, 293 и сл.;
>   Эндзелин, СБЭ 198; М.-Э. 2, 102; Бернекер I, 459; Мейе — Вайан 39;
>   Мейе — Эрну 590 и сл.; Перссон, IF 2, 244 и сл.

https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D1%8E/%D1%8E%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Так что уный в др.-рус. то же, что юный, а уне - наречие "лучше". И орфография другая, и звучание.